# Why i'm not able to deploy my vite app on vercel

Tags: reactjs, vite, mern, vercel

Im trying to build a social media app using Vite but the main problem is its not getting deployed anyhow. Im adding my vite.config.js file for better understading. The main problem im facing is the ./ route is getting shown but other routes are undefined.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

[image: its ./ route here my ./home route is rendered]

[image: this is ./signin page its not defined]

any sort of help will really be appreciated

Comment: In your code, could you search for `.pic` and see if the left side of `whatever.pic` here `whatever` is `undefined` as per the error or you can use optional chaining as `whatever?.pic` ...

Comment: the main problem here is this is the ./home page which is okk and working but other routes are not defined and not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with SPAs which occurs while working with child paths/routes. This is not specific to **vercel** and even occurs on other platforms as well, Here is something you can try with vercel:

Create a `vercel.json` file within the *root folder* of your project. Add this config to the file:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }
  ]
}
```

As mentioned in this [doc](https://dev.to/david_bilsonn/how-to-fix-vercel-404-error-child-url-path-issues-n0o) as well:

> "rewrites" specifies the rules for URL rewrites. `{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }` tells Vercel that for any URL path that matches
> `/(.*)` (essentially any path), redirect the request to the root path
> (/).

Comment: npm ERR! Missing script: "vite"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-03-09T06_43_17_719Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm run vite build" exited with 1

Comment: It looks like a different error. You are trying to run a script that doesn't exist in your package.json